# Setting TextYankPost v:event attributes in lua

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to fix a bug in a plugin that manually fires "TextYankPost" like:

```
vim.api.nvim_exec_autocmds("TextYankPost", {})
```

This does not set v:event.regcontents, which causes problems with callback listeners.

I have tried to use:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_vvar("event", '')
```

but the event variable is readonly. What are my options to set the necessary values for v:event